Is there a remote write for tracing tools?
Currently I am trying to push my telemetry data collected by open telemetry to Grafana cloud. I manage to push my metrics using Prometheus remote write.
global:
  scrape_interval: 60s
remote_write:
  - url: https://prometheus-xx.grafana.net/api/prom/push
    basic_auth:
      username: xx
      password: xx
scrape_configs:
   - job_name: 'otel-collector'
     scrape_interval: 3s
     static_configs:
       - targets: ['otel:8889']
       - targets: ['otel:8888']
       - targets: ["localhost:9090"]

However, I also want to push my tracing data to grafana cloud, but I can't really find the way.
For tracing currently I am using zipkin. Is there anyway I can push it directly to grafana? I looked around Tempo, but I think there is no remote write as well
This is my configuration for open-telemetry
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:

exporters:
  zipkin:
    endpoint: "http://zipkin:9411/api/v2/spans"
  prometheus:
    endpoint: "0.0.0.0:8889"

processors:
  batch:

extensions:
  health_check:
  pprof:
    endpoint: :1888
  zpages:
    endpoint: :55679

service:
  extensions: [pprof, zpages, health_check]
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [zipkin]
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [prometheus]

and my docker compose
version: '3.4'

services:
  zipkin:
    image: openzipkin/zipkin
    container_name: zipkin
    ports:
      - 9411:9411

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    container_name: prometheus
    volumes:
      -  ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"

  otel:
    image: otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib
    container_name: otel
    command: ["--config=/etc/otel-collector-config.yaml"]
    volumes:
      -  ./otel-collector-config.yaml:/etc/otel-collector-config.yaml
    ports:
      - "1888:1888"   # pprof extension
      - "8888:8888"   # Prometheus metrics exposed by the collector
      - "8889:8889"   # Prometheus exporter metrics
      - "13133:13133" # health_check extension
      - "4317:4317"        # OTLP gRPC receiver
      - "55670:55679" # zpages extension
    depends_on:
      - zipkin
      - prometheus


I haven't tested this, but it looks like you should be able to add Grafana Cloud as an otlphttp exporter endpoint directly.
